# Stripe & Rails - securly passing final amount to charges controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments

I'm integrating Stripe payments into a site that sells event tickets.

I have no need for a shopping cart, but I am presenting users with a summary page before making the final payment.

What I can't figure out is the best way to then pass the total due to my charges controller. Sure, I could work out ways of passing the value easy enough but I'm keen to know what others suggest is the most secure way of doing this.

So, working through what I have:

My event show view has the following form to allow users to pick the tickets they want (an event can have many ticket types) and then the qty.

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <tr>
    <th>Ticket Type</th>
    <th>On Sale Until</th>    
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>

<%= form_tag tickets_path do %>
<% @event.event_tickets.each do |ticket| %>

  <tr>
    <td><%= ticket.ticket_type_name %></td>
    <td><%= ticket.off_sale_date.to_formatted_s(:my_format) %></td>   
    <td><%= ticket.price %></td>
    <td>

    <%= select_tag "qty[#{ticket.id}]", "<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>".html_safe, :class => "input-mini select-mini" %><br>

    <%= hidden_field_tag "ticket_id[]", ticket.id %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= submit_tag 'Buy Tickets', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

My events controller has a tickets action whose sole purpose is to calculate and display the total (and eventually a summary) to the customer.

```
  def tickets
    @event = Event.find_by_slug!(params[:id])

    @sub_totals = []
    @qty_array = [] 
    @keys = params[:qty].each do |ticket_id,qty|
       ticket_price = EventTicket.find(ticket_id)
       @sub_totals.push(ticket_price.price.to_f * qty.to_i)
       @qty_array.push(qty.to_i)
    end

    @total = @sub_totals.inject(:+)

  end
```

Params passed look like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"abc123", "qty"=>{"4"=>"3", "5"=>"1"}, "ticket_id"=>["4", "5"], "commit"=>"Buy Tickets", "id"=>"test-with-tickets"}
```

Where the main param i'm using is the qty hash which is "ticket_id" => "qty".

So, my next step is to pass the total to my charges controller, but in theory I would also want the ticket ids and qtys.

I may be answering this myself here, but instead of passing the total, should I start by extracting the totalling code to a model method that I can call from both the event/tickets and charges/create actions based on the "ticket_id" => "qty" hash? If that's a better approach, how should I securely pass that hash from the event/tickets summary to the charges/create action so that users aren't able to tamper with ids and/or qtys?

I hope that all makes some sense?

Comment: Doing a bit of further reading myself; is SSL the answer to this?

Comment: I'd suggest adding Order/LineItems models and capturing what the user has requested (tix, quantities, etc).  That provides you with a single number to pass among controllers without the users having the ability to alter the contents to which the number points.  More importantly, it will provide you with a transactional model that will allow you to track who requested which tickets and when, a convenient way to generate your summary, ... and a place to wrap up the totalling logic.

Comment: That make sense, I was originally going to go this route. Would you suggest I then mark the orders complete when the stripe payment is successful or copy the completed orders to a new model? Also, I'd need to add in some logic to clear down incomplete orders which I can't imagine will be too hard.

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable.  FWIW, I really like the state_machine gem for handling state transitions like that.  https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine